# Static link with Premake

Tags: premake

I'm using premake4 on Linux to build a project which links to a third party .a file.

Neither `links {"foo"}` nor `links {"libfoo.a"}` work, since premake generates a build script which incorrectly uses the flag `-lfoo` as if I'm linking a shared library. Using `files {"libfoo.a"}` will make premake ignore the file since it isn't C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premake4 is getting awfully old at this point. Is switching to [Premake5](http://premake.github.io) an option?

If not, one hacky workaround would be to use [linkoptions](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/linkoptions) to emit the link flags however you would like them to appear.

Comment: I suppose it's time to switch. Thanks, `links {"foo"}` works with Premake5.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking with my question actually. Premake4 works just fine as well with `links {"foo"}` too.